# Store encrypted file on disk from service

Tags: encryption

I am a windows service that downloads and saves oAuth tokens and I need to store them encrypted  on the local hard drive until they expire and reuse them later. The problem being a service is that I cannot ask the user for a password. Is there a safe or suggested method to secure files when storing them and prevent other processes decrypting it? My language of choice is python and it would be relatively easy for someone to find out the encryption algorithm.

Comment: Sorry if the question is to broad, but what I am after is the logic and not an actual implementation.

Comment: Note that there is also the IT security sister site at https://security.stackexchange.com/. You can ask there but please first search for duplicates. Note that they may see your question as off topic here as well because it is missing use cases / threat vectors and such. Without a model, it is hard to recommend any protocols or algorithms.

Comment: By the way, I didn't know that AI got so advanced that Windows services can ask for a security protocol on StackOverflow. Welcome to the land of conscious beings.